# css/javascript rotation but not from centre

Tags: jquery, css, rotation, transform

I wish to create a hover rotation effect using css or javascript but instead of rotating from the centre like it usually does i wish to rotate from the top left point of the square.

The square will rotate 90 degrees on hover then back on mouse out. Can i widen the hover area to avoid the square to flutter(repeat constantly).

I will try to show my thought process using awful diagrams, the cross is the rotation point.

```
_________
|       |
|   +   |
|       |
---------
```

to this:

```
+--------         
|       |   
|       |   
|       |   
---------
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `transform-origin`:

```
transform-origin: 0 0;
```

And a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ssRS4/2/

Comment: Is it possible to widen the area of the hover function, if I set your demo to a rotate when hover, the mouse needs to be a certain place to avoid repetition. the square only needs to rotate 90 degrees on hover and move back

Comment: Add a bug parent element and use `.parent:hover .child` to affect the child element.